# snmpd not found issue?

Tags: package, snmp, rhel, net-snmp

I've installed the net-snmp package (version 5.8) by downloading the tar.gz file and compiling the files inside on a RHEL server (version 6.9).

I can see that the package is installed when I type `snmpd --version` but whenever I try to use `service snmpd restart` it says `snmpd: unrecognized service`.

I did all the setups and the `snmpd.conf` file was created (but not at /etc/snmp/ for some reason initially, so I copied the file there) but it seems like `snmpd` isn't being recognized at all.

I even tried `snmpd restart` but nothing happens and it seems like the SNMP connection still isn't there either.

Is there a way to fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Do you *really* have to use that recent version? If you go the route of packaged install via `yum install net-snmp`, you will have everything ready to work out of the box.  Using any non-RPM based install implies that you know what you're doing and for a service, at minimum requires creating a startup file at `/etc/rc.d/init.d/snmpd`

Comment: I wish I could use ```yum``` as well, but the server I'm working on has a firewall set up so it blocks the server from downloading anything. I had to WinSCP the tar.gz file to the server from a connected PC to do anything. Is there any way I could get the RPM- based install to work without having a connection? Like is there a RPM package I can download to my PC and then send it to the server to install? Thanks!

Comment: Also, I don't know how to set up a startup file at ```/etc/rc.d/init.d/snmpd``` at all. btw I'm new at this so it would be great if you could help. Thanks!

Comment: I would rather question what is the point of this firewall. If it was put intentional, then it's a bit silly - you seem to resort to installing non-packaged software due to this, which is a security risk of its own (what you manually install, is highly likely not going to be ever updated/patched after being installed).

Comment: The firewall exists because the servers are used for receiving and sending data from specific points, and it has somehow been hacked before when the firewall wasn't set up. That's all I know about it. I wish I could disable it as well but it's supposedly too risky to do so. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a firewall blocking data transfer for protected machines, but that's no reason to use a different version of the software or to build it from source. Using a different computer, download the package, then WinSCP the `.rpm` as you did with the `tar.gz`, do a `yum localinstall`, and away you go!

Comment: @DanilaVershinin On the other hand, if the machine is quarantined from the internet, you probably don't really care so much about patching away security risks. This is quite common in enterprise. Not everybody's computer is online.

Comment: Thanks! But do you know where to find ```.rpm``` for RHEL distributions? I can find ones for CentOS but I'm not sure if it's okay to install the CentOS version...

Comment: I managed to find the rpm packages but it seems like it's giving me some issues:

```Error: Package: 1:net-snmp-5.6.1-1.fc15.i386 (/net-snmp-5.6.1-1.fc14.i386)
           Requires: libnetsnmpmibs.so.25
Error: Package: 1:net-snmp-5.6.1-1.fc15.i386 (/net-snmp-5.6.1-1.fc14.i386)
           Requires: libnetsnmpagent.so.25
Error: Package: 1:net-snmp-5.6.1-1.fc15.i386 (/net-snmp-5.6.1-1.fc14.i386)
           Requires: libnetsnmp.so.25```


I got the packages from ```https://sourceforge.net/projects/net-snmp/files/OldFiles/net-snmp-5.6.x/5.6.1-binaries/```

Did I get the right files?